# Mistake on a Major Maths Website

Tags: logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion

I think I have found two massive errors on [Math.com](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log.htm) but I throw my logic out here for a third party to verify as I've been doing Contour Integrals for about 10 hours straight now so I am very tired.

If you navigate to [Math.com](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log.htm)'s logarithmic expansion page the following identities are given at the bottom:

$$
    \tag{1}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^n}{n} = -x +\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{2}x^4 + \cdots = -\ln{(x)} \quad\text{if}\ -1 < x \leq 1
$$

and 
$$
    \tag{2}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n} = x +\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{2}x^4 + \cdots = -\ln{(x+1)} \quad\text{if}\ -1 < x \leq 1
$$

However, the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) is well known and defined as,

$$
    \ln{(x+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n} = x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{1}{2}x^4 + \cdots \quad\text{if}\ -1 < x \leq 1
$$

Taking the known result for the Mercator series, we can can show that Equation 1, is clearly incorrect,
$$
    \tag{3}
    \ln{(x+1)} = (-1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^n}{n} \ne (-1)\ln{(x)}
$$
as this is the negative of [Math.com](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log.htm)'s definition in Equation 1!

Multiplying both sides of Equation 3 by $-1$, we get,
$$
    -\ln{(x+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^n}{n} \ne \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}
$$
but this clearly is not equal to the second identity given on [Math.com](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log.htm) and they are missing a factor of $(-1)^n$ in the summation.

Comment: The series $(2)$ diverges for $x=1$.

Comment: @Bernard I agree, it's just completely wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mercator series is indeed
$$
\log(1+x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}=
-\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^n}{n}
$$
so the series (1) is just $-\log(1+x)$ (convergent for $-1<x\le 1$).

If we change $x$ into $-x$, we get
$$
-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n(-x)^n}{n}=
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^n}{n}
$$
which converges for $-1\le x<1$.

There is clearly a typo in relation (1) (missing $1\:+$); relation (2) is clearly wrong for $x=1/2$, because the left-hand side is positive and the right-hand side is negative. With $1-x$, instead, it's correct.

Comment: thanks for checking, I tried to actually get in contact to get them to change it but they're owned by some random company who makes it a pain to get in contact with. It's one of the first results for a search on "Logarithmic Expansions" which is awkward.